# ERROR: ОШИБКА: отношение "city_id_seq" уже существует

Tags: sql, postgresql

Создаю из 1125 городов базу, но высвечивается ошибка при выполнении кода. Использую postgresql и создаю запрос в pgAdmin 4

Ошибка:

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  отношение "city_id_seq" уже существует


SQL-состояние: 42P07
```

Запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id SERIAL,
  id_region integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO city (id, id_region, name) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Адыгейск'),
(2, 1, 'Майкоп'),
(3, 2, 'Горно-Алтайск'),
(4, 3, 'Алейск'),
(5, 3, 'Барнаул'),
(6, 3, 'Белокуриха'),
(7, 3, 'Бийск'),
(8, 3, 'Горняк'),
(9, 3, 'Заринск'),
(10, 3, 'Змеиногорск'),
(11, 3, 'Камень-на-Оби'),
(12, 3, 'Новоалтайск'),
(13, 3, 'Рубцовск'),
(14, 3, 'Славгород'),
(15, 3, 'Яровое'),
(16, 4, 'Белогорск'),
(17, 4, 'Благовещенск'),
(18, 4, 'Завитинск'),
(19, 4, 'Зея'),
(20, 4, 'Райчихинск'),
(21, 4, 'Свободный'),
(22, 4, 'Сковородино'),
(23, 4, 'Тында'),
(24, 4, 'Шимановск'),
(25, 5, 'Архангельск'),
(26, 5, 'Вельск'),
(27, 5, 'Каргополь'),
(28, 5, 'Коряжма'),
(29, 5, 'Котлас'),
(30, 5, 'Мезень'),
(31, 5, 'Мирный'),
(32, 5, 'Новодвинск'),
(33, 5, 'Няндома'),
(34, 5, 'Онега'),
(35, 5, 'Северодвинск'),
(36, 5, 'Сольвычегодск'),
(37, 5, 'Шенкурск'),
(38, 6, 'Астрахань'),
(39, 6, 'Ахтубинск'),
(40, 6, 'Знаменск'),
(41, 6, 'Камызяк'),
(42, 6, 'Нариманов'),
(43, 6, 'Харабали'),
(44, 7, 'Агидель'),
(45, 7, 'Баймак'),
(46, 7, 'Белебей'),
(47, 7, 'Белорецк'),
(48, 7, 'Бирск'),
(49, 7, 'Благовещенск'),
(50, 7, 'Давлеканово'),
(51, 7, 'Дюртюли'),
(52, 7, 'Ишимбай'),
(53, 7, 'Кумертау'),
(54, 7, 'Межгорье'),
(55, 7, 'Мелеуз'),
(56, 7, 'Нефтекамск'),
(57, 7, 'Октябрьский'),
(58, 7, 'Салават'),
(59, 7, 'Сибай'),
(60, 7, 'Стерлитамак'),
(61, 7, 'Туймазы'),
(62, 7, 'Уфа'),
(63, 7, 'Учалы'),
(64, 7, 'Янаул'),
(65, 8, 'Алексеевка'),
(66, 8, 'Белгород'),
(67, 8, 'Бирюч'),
(68, 8, 'Валуйки'),
(69, 8, 'Грайворон'),
(70, 8, 'Губкин'),
(71, 8, 'Короча'),
(72, 8, 'Новый Оскол'),
(73, 8, 'Старый Оскол'),
(74, 8, 'Строитель'),
(75, 8, 'Шебекино'),
(76, 9, 'Брянск'),
(77, 9, 'Дятьково'),
(78, 9, 'Жуковка'),
(79, 9, 'Злынка'),
(80, 9, 'Карачев'),
(81, 9, 'Клинцы'),
(82, 9, 'Мглин'),
(83, 9, 'Новозыбков'),
(84, 9, 'Почеп'),
(85, 9, 'Севск'),
(86, 9, 'Сельцо'),
(87, 9, 'Стародуб'),
(88, 9, 'Сураж'),
(89, 9, 'Трубчевск'),
(90, 9, 'Унеча'),
(91, 9, 'Фокино'),
(92, 10, 'Бабушкин'),
(93, 10, 'Гусиноозёрск'),
(94, 10, 'Закаменск'),
(95, 10, 'Кяхта'),
(96, 10, 'Северобайкальск'),
(97, 10, 'Улан-Удэ'),
(98, 11, 'Александров'),
(99, 11, 'Владимир'),
(100, 11, 'Вязники'),
(101, 11, 'Гороховец'),
(102, 11, 'Гусь-Хрустальный'),
(103, 11, 'Камешково'),
(104, 11, 'Карабаново'),
(105, 11, 'Киржач'),
(106, 11, 'Ковров'),
(107, 11, 'Кольчугино'),
(108, 11, 'Костерёво'),
(109, 11, 'Курлово'),
(110, 11, 'Лакинск'),
(111, 11, 'Меленки'),
(112, 11, 'Муром'),
(113, 11, 'Петушки'),
(114, 11, 'Покров'),
(115, 11, 'Радужный'),
(116, 11, 'Собинка'),
(117, 11, 'Струнино'),
(118, 11, 'Судогда'),
(119, 11, 'Суздаль'),
(120, 11, 'Юрьев-Польский'),
(121, 12, 'Волгоград'),
(122, 12, 'Волжский'),
(123, 12, 'Дубовка'),
(124, 12, 'Жирновск'),
(125, 12, 'Калач-на-Дону'),
(126, 12, 'Камышин'),
(127, 12, 'Котельниково'),
(128, 12, 'Котово'),
(129, 12, 'Краснослободск'),
(130, 12, 'Ленинск'),
(131, 12, 'Михайловка'),
(132, 12, 'Николаевск'),
(133, 12, 'Новоаннинский'),
(134, 12, 'Палласовка'),
(135, 12, 'Петров Вал'),
(136, 12, 'Серафимович'),
(137, 12, 'Суровикино'),
(138, 12, 'Урюпинск'),
(139, 12, 'Фролово'),
(140, 13, 'Бабаево'),
(141, 13, 'Белозерск'),
(142, 13, 'Великий Устюг'),
(143, 13, 'Вологда'),
(144, 13, 'Вытегра'),
(145, 13, 'Грязовец'),
(146, 13, 'Кадников'),
(147, 13, 'Кириллов'),
(148, 13, 'Красавино'),
(149, 13, 'Никольск'),
(150, 13, 'Сокол'),
(151, 13, 'Тотьма'),
(152, 13, 'Устюжна'),
(153, 13, 'Харовск'),
(154, 13, 'Череповец'),
(155, 14, 'Бобров'),
(156, 14, 'Богучар'),
(157, 14, 'Борисоглебск'),
(158, 14, 'Бутурлиновка'),
(159, 14, 'Воронеж'),
(160, 14, 'Калач'),
(161, 14, 'Лиски'),
(162, 14, 'Нововоронеж'),
(163, 14, 'Новохопёрск'),
(164, 14, 'Острогожск'),
(165, 14, 'Павловск'),
(166, 14, 'Поворино'),
(167, 14, 'Россошь'),
(168, 14, 'Семилуки'),
(169, 14, 'Эртиль'),
(170, 15, 'Буйнакск'),
(171, 15, 'Республика Дагестанские Огни'),
(172, 15, 'Дербент'),
(173, 15, 'Избербаш'),
(174, 15, 'Каспийск'),
(175, 15, 'Кизилюрт'),
(176, 15, 'Кизляр'),
(177, 15, 'Махачкала'),
(178, 15, 'Хасавюрт'),
...
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что вы пытаетесь определить сразу два столбца с именем `id`? А вот базу это озадачивает.

Comment: Исправил и заработало, спасибо. Могли бы указать это ответом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка, конечно, на самом деле должна быть

> column "id" specified more than once

Потому что именно это неверно в вашем `create table`. Вы пытаетесь создать два поля `id`.

Ошибка же `relation "city_id_seq" already exists` (`отношение "city_id_seq" уже существует`) проистекает от того, что первое поле `serial` выбирает для себя свободное название сиквенса и делает соответствующий `create sequence city_id_seq`, затем второе обнаруженное поле `serial` по ошибке выбирает то же самое название сиквенса и пытается его создать второй раз. Закономерно получая ошибку на этом этапе.